# How can I create a complete_name field in a custom module for a custom hierarchy like used on product categories in Odoo?

Tags: odoo-9

I'm trying to create a field “complete_name” that displays a hierarchy name similar to whats done on the product categories grid but I can't seem to get it to work. It just puts Odoo in an endless loading screen when I access the relevant view using the new field "complete_name".

I have tried to copy the code used in [addons/product/product.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/product/product.py#L204) and migrate to work with Odoo 9 API by using compute instead of .function type but it did not work.
Can someone help me understand whats wrong? Below is my model class which works fine without the complete_name field in my view.

```
class cb_public_catalog_category( models.Model ):
    _name = "cb.public.catalog.category" 
    _parent_store = True     
    parent_left = newFields.Integer( index = True ) 
    parent_right = newFields.Integer( index = True )
    name = newFields.Char( string = 'Category Name' ) 
    child_id = newFields.One2many( 'catalog.category', 'parent_id', string = 'Child Categories' ) 
    complete_name = newFields.Char( compute = '_name_get_fnc', string = 'Name' )

def _name_get_fnc( self ):
    res = self.name_get( self ) 
    return dict( res )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compute function is supposed to define the value of an attribute of your class, not return a value. Ensure the value you are assigning `complete_name` is a string.

Also name_get() returns a tuple. I am not sure if you really want a string representation of this tuple or just the actual name value.

Try this

```
def _name_get_fnc( self ):
    self.complete_name = self.name_get()[1]
```

If you really want what is returned by `name_get()` then try this.

```
def _name_get_fnc( self ):
    self.complete_name = str(self.name_get())
```

If you are still having issues I would incorporate some logging to get a better idea of what you are setting the value of complete_name to.

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _name_get_fnc( self ):
    _logger.info("COMPUTING COMPLETE NAME")
    _logger.info("COMPLETE NAME: " + str(self.name_get()))
    self.complete_name = self.name_get()
```

If this does not make it apparent what the issue is you could always try statically assigning it a value in the off chance that there  is a problem with your view.

```
def _name_get_fnc( self ):
    self.complete_name = "TEST COMPLETE NAME"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'm sure your answer will come in handy for another user trying to do something similar but as it turned out my answer was much simpler. I was just doing it all wrong lol.

Answer (score 0):

After further review I think I have the answer to my own question. It turns out as with a lot of things its very simple.

Simply use "_inherit" and inherit the product.category
model. This gives access to all the functions and fields
of product.category including the complete_name field
and computes the name from my custom model data. I was
able to remove my _name_get_func and just use the inherited
function.

The final model definition is below. Once this 
update was complete I was able to add a "complete_name" field
to my view and the results were as desired!

```
class cb_public_catalog_category( models.Model ):
     _name = "cb.public.catalog.category" 
     _inherit = 'product.category'
     _parent_store = True     
     parent_left = newFields.Integer( index = True ) 
     parent_right = newFields.Integer( index = True )
     name = newFields.Char( string = 'Category Name' ) 
     child_id = newFields.One2many( 'catalog.category', 'parent_id', string = 'Child Categories' )
```